# package variable scope in module subroutine

Tags: perl, perl-module

How do I change the value of a variable in the package used by a module so that subroutines in that module can use it?

Here's my test case:

testmodule.pm:

```
package testmodule;

use strict;
use warnings;
require Exporter;

our ($VERSION, @ISA, @EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK, %EXPORT_TAGS);

@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(testsub);

my $greeting = "hello testmodule";
my $var2;

sub testsub {
    printf "__PACKAGE__: %s\n", __PACKAGE__;
    printf "\$main::greeting: %s\n", $main::greeting;
    printf "\$greeting: %s\n", $greeting;
    printf "\$testmodule::greeting: %s\n", $testmodule::greeting;
    printf "\$var2: %s\n", $var2;
} # End testsub
1;
```

testscript.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use testmodule;

our $greeting = "hello main";
my $var2 = "my var2 in testscript";

$testmodule::greeting = "hello testmodule from testscript";
$testmodule::var2 = "hello var2 from testscript";

testsub();
```

output:

```
Name "testmodule::var2" used only once: possible typo at ./testscript.pl line 11.
__PACKAGE__: testmodule
$main::greeting: hello main
$greeting: hello testmodule
$testmodule::greeting: hello testmodule from testscript
Use of uninitialized value $var2 in printf at testmodule.pm line 20.
$var2:
```

I expected `$greeting` and `$testmodule::greeting` to be the same since the package of the subroutine is `testmodule`.

I guess this has something to do with the way `use`d modules are `eval`d as if in a `BEGIN` block, but I'd like to understand it better.

I was hoping to set the value of the variable from the main script and use it in the module's subroutine without using the fully-qualified name of the variable.

Comment: The "Subroutines" chapter of _Learning Perl_ explains this.

Comment: If you're doing testing, take a look at the Perl testing modules (http://qa.perl.org/test-modules.html).  Test::More is a good place to start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading [Variable Scoping in Perl: the basics](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=66677) more carefully, I realized that a variable declared with `my` isn't in the current package.  For example, in a simple script with no modules if I declare `my $var = "hello"` `$main::var` still doesn't have a value.

The way that this applies in this case is in the module.  Since `my $greeting` is declared in the file, that hides the package's version of `$greeting` and that's the value which the subroutine sees.  If I don't declare the variable first, the subroutine would see the package variable, but it doesn't get that far because I `use strict`.

If I don't `use strict` and don't declare `my $greeting`, it works as I would have expected.  Another way to get the intended value and not break `use strict` is to use `our $greeting`.  The difference being that [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) declares a variable in the current ***scope*** while [our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) declares a variable in the current ***package***.

Answer (score 14):

As you found out, when you use `my`, you are creating a locally scoped **non-package** variable. To create a package variable, you use `our` and not `my`:

```
my $foo = "this is a locally scoped, non-package variable";
our $bar = "This is a package variable that's visible in the entire package";
```

Even better:

```
{
   my $foo = "This variable is only available in this block";
   our $bar = "This variable is available in the whole package":
}

print "$foo\n";    #Whoops! Undefined variable
print "$bar\n";    #Bar is still defined even out of the block
```

When you don't put `use strict` in your program, all variables defined are package variables. That's why when you don't put it, it works the way you think it should and putting it in *breaks* your program.

However, as you can see in the following example, using `our` will solve your dilemma:

### File `Local/Foo.pm`

```
#! /usr/local/bin perl
package Local::Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw(testme);

our $bar = "This is the package's bar value!";
sub testme {

    # $foo is a locally scoped, non-package variable. It's undefined and an error
    say qq(The value of \$main::foo is "$main::foo");

    # $bar is defined in package main::, and will print out
    say qq(The value of \$main::bar is "$main::bar");

    # These both refer to $Local::Foo::bar
    say qq(The value of \$Local::Foo::bar is "$Local::Foo::bar");
    say qq(The value of bar is "$bar");
}

1;
```

### File `test.pl`

```
#! /usr/local/bin perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Local::Foo;

my $foo = "This is foo";
our $bar = "This is bar";
testme;

say "";
$Local::Foo::bar = "This is the NEW value for the package's bar";
testme
```

And, the output is:

```
Use of uninitialized value $foo in concatenation (.) or string at Local/Foo.pm line 14.
The value of $main::foo is ""
The value of $main::bar is "This is bar"
The value of $Local::Foo::bar is "This is the package's bar value!"
The value of bar is "This is the package's bar value!"

Use of uninitialized value $foo in concatenation (.) or string at Local/Foo.pm line 14.
The value of $main::foo is ""
The value of $main::bar is "This is bar"
The value of $Local::Foo::bar is "This is the NEW value for the package's bar"
The value of bar is "This is the NEW value for the package's bar"
```

The error message you're getting is the result of `$foo` being a local variable, and thus isn't visible inside the package. Meanwhile, `$bar` is a package variable and is visible.

Sometimes, it can be a bit tricky:

```
if ($bar -eq "one") {
   my $foo = 1;
}
else {
   my $foo = 2;
}

print "Foo = $foo\n";
```

That doesn't work because `$foo` only bas a value inside the `if` block. You have to do this:

```
my $foo;
if ($bar -eq "one") {
   $foo = 1;
}
else {
  $foo = 2;
}

print "Foo = $foo\n"; #This works!
```

Yes, it can be a bit to get your head wrapped around it initially, but the use of `use strict;` and `use warnings;` is now de rigueur and for good reasons. The use of `use strict;` and `use warnings;` probably has eliminated 90% of the mistakes people make in Perl. You can't make a mistake of setting the value of `$foo` in one part of the program, and attempting to use `$Foo` in another. It's one of the things I really miss in Python.

Comment: Excellent explanation and examples, solved and understood all my problems as a result. thanks

Comment: Searched for answer to accessing module variables, learned more about variable scoping. Good answer +1

Comment: I found the real gold in this answer to be the `use strict` note.  I have modules with and without `use strict` and couldn't figure out why some worked.  I know the correct answer is to always `use strict;`, but stuff happens.  Thanks, and +1.